# what's going on when I setq a parameter variable in a defun? (Emacs)

Tags: function, emacs, parameters, elisp

```
(defun make-it-5 (num)
  (setq num 5))
(setq a 0)
(make-it-5 a)
;; now a is still 0, not 5.
```

In the above code, it seems neither (setq a 5) nor (setq 0 5) happens. If (setq a 5) happened, then a would have changed to 5, but a is still 0. If (setq 0 5) happened, Lisp error would have occurred. What does happen? That is my question.

For some of you who got here by googling and wondering how to make make-it-5 work as its name suggest, one way is

```
(defmacro make-it-7 (num) ; defmacro instead of defun
  `(setq ,num 7))
(setq a 0)
(make-it-7 a)
;; now a is 7.
```

Another is:

```
(defun make-it-plus (num-var)
  (set num-var (+ 1 (symbol-value num-var))) ; `set' instead of `setq'
) 
(setq a 0)
(make-it-plus 'a) ; 'a instead of a
;; now a is 1.
```

Comment: The question is a bit confusing .  The two alternatives you provide both require a more detailed understanding of lisp (emacs-lisp).  I'm guessing you don't understand how those work either...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The short answer is that the `(setq num 5)` [changes the binding for](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Setting-Variables.html#Setting-Variables) `num`, which is a binding local to the `make-it-5` function.

A breakdown follows.  It's good to make sure you're familiar with the notion of [evaluation](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Intro-Eval.html#Intro-Eval).

When the `(make-it-5 a)` is evaluated, the interpreter looks for a function in the first element of the expression.  In this case, the first element is a symbol (`make-it-5` - which means it is a  [named function](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Function-Names.html#Function-Names)), so it looks in the symbol's [function cell](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Symbol-Components.html#Symbol-Components).  Note: this lookup can repeat itself, see [Symbol Function Indirection](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Function-Indirection.html#Function-Indirection).

The rest of the elements of the expression are evaluated to find values.  In this case, there's just one symbol (`a`), and so the interpreter returns [the contents of its value cell](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Symbol-Forms.html#Symbol-Forms), which is `0`.

The interpreter then applies the function to the list of arguments, which involves making [local bindings between its arguments to the values passed in](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Simple-Lambda.html#Simple-Lambda).  In this case, a [local binding](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Local-Variables.html#Local-Variables) between the symbol `num` and the value `0` is made.  Then the body of the function is evaluated in that environment.

The body is just a single expression which is a "call" to [`setq`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Setting-Variables.html#Setting-Variables).  I put "call" in quotes because `setq` is a [special form](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Special-Forms.html#Special-Forms) and doesn't evaluate its first argument, but looks up the symbol and sets the [most local existing binding](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Variable-Scoping.html#Variable-Scoping), which is the binding created inside the function `make-it-5`.

So, you're changing the binding for the symbol `num` which is local to the function `make-it-5`.